# Azure APIM Prod and Non-Prod on single instance

Tags: azure-api-management, apim

Is it possible to have logical separation of Azure APIM service i.e one could work like Prod and Non-Prod at the same time?

Comment: You could separate your APIs by using products, ie "My Product Production" and "My Product Development"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check this [Azure API Management DevOps Resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/devops-api-development-templates) you would find that Microsoft recommends to use **separate Azure API Management service instances for various environments**, such as production, development, and QA. Where these environments are generally shared by multiple development teams, each responsible for a subset of APIs. It is the **best practice for the enterprise setup**.

But if you don't want to create multiple instances then, you could try using versions and revisions.

- You can create **revisions** by right clicking API and click "Add Revision".
- Similarly you can create **versions** by right clicking API and click "Add Version".

For more information check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59908878) by @DSpirit on the similar problem shared in Stack Overflow.

Comment: I don't read your linked article the same way you read it. I read it as set each developer up their own private APIM instance with consumption or developer SKU. I don't see anything about different environments

"Set up an Azure API Management service for each API developer so that they can develop API definitions along with the API service. Use the consumption or developer SKU when creating the service."